# Is there a maximum of simultaneous localhost cUrl request with PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm setting up a vuejs app and multiple Laravel applications that must communicate between them. Communication between Laravel applications are done through cUrl request. For now, everything are on my dev machines (Last MacBook Pro - Mac OS Majove) with the help of MAMP Pro (PHP 7.3).
Problem is when I do simultaneous queries, I had a :

`CURL error 28 communication timeout ... with 0 bytes received.`

It if of course not a timeout problem (I tried with 2 minutes on all applications and all timeouts - same result). Since I'm working with API, there is no PHP session (so no session file lock).

It seems that cUrl connection is closed but I don't know why (I don't close it myself - and it don't hit the timeouts (connect/read/global) ).

More visually :

```
vuejs --ajax1--> Laravel A --cUrl--> Laravel B --cUrl--> Laravel C
vuejs --ajax2--> Laravel A --cUrl--> Laravel B --cUrl--> Laravel C

vuejs <--500-- Laravel A --X-- Laravel B <---- Laravel C
vuejs <--500-- Laravel A --X-- Laravel B <---- Laravel C

ajax1 and ajax2 are sent at the same time.
```

It is working if `ajax1` and `ajax2` are sent NOT at the same time.

What I know:

- Communication is cut between `Laravel A` and `Laravel B` but `Laravel B`
  execute the code en return a response (that never arrived because, I think, connection is closed ?). But both request hit `Laravel C` and `Laravel C` also runs.

What I tried:

- Apache and nginx
- Disable firewall
- Increase all timeouts (PHP - cUrl)
- Increase memory limit (PHP)
- cUrl `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` and `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` options
- Change local domain name and tld of Laravel applications

What I wondering:

- Is there a maximum requests that I can do, at the same time, with cUrl on the same machine (I, of course, set `CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS` to 20 - without success) ?
- Is there a PHP.ini configuration that I missed ?
- Is it possible that the problem come from the fact that all these applications run on the same machine ? If yes, why ?
- Are both servers (nginx and Apache) limits connection from same IP ? (since all applications are on the same machine, they all have the same IP).

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into the same problem. Where main backend is acting as a proxy to get data from other backend through curl(guzzle).

But i get timeout only if doing more than 5 simultaneous requests.
All applications are live and i've tried setting up a new VPS server to avoid having all backends on the same machine.
Setting CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS also didn't work.

This is my fake proxy code(using laravel)

```
    $uri = $request->get('url');
    $api_url = env('URL');

    $token = env('TOKEN');
    $key = 'Bearer ' . $token;

    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $api_url,
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => $key
        ]
    ]);

    $request = $client->request('GET', $uri, [
        'http_errors' => false
    ]);


    $response = $request->getBody()->getContents();

    return $response;
```

I haven't found a solution yet. Hopefully someone could help us solving this problem.